# I'don't understand leet code variable declaration

Tags: c++

Correct Solution

```
class Solution {
public:
    int pivotIndex(vector<int>& nums) {
        int rightsum = 0;
        int leftsum = 0; // this problem point
        
        for(int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++){
            rightsum += nums[i];
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++){
            rightsum -= nums[i];
            if(rightsum == leftsum) {
                return i;
            }
            leftsum += nums[i];
        };
        
        return -1;
    }
};
```

Wrong Solution

```
class Solution {
public:
    int pivotIndex(vector<int>& nums) {
        int rightsum, leftsum = 0; // this problem point
        
        for(int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++){
            rightsum += nums[i];
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++){
            rightsum -= nums[i];
            if(rightsum == leftsum) {
                return i;
            }
            leftsum += nums[i];
        };
        
        return -1;
    }
};
```

I can't understand both code difference.
Can both code be able to declare variable?
It was possible when coding in Dev-C++, but not here.
What's different?

Comment: Is it possible in Dev C++ to declare and initialize two variables as `int rightsum, leftsum = 0;` really??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This

```
int rightsum, leftsum = 0; // this problem point
```

is equivalent to

```
int rightsum;
int leftsum = 0;
```

`rightsum` is not initialized, it has an indeterminate value. Then here

```
rightsum += nums[i];
```

you are reading from `rightsum` before initializing it. That is undefined behavior. It is possible that in a debug build `rightsum` was initialized with `0`, or you were just very unlucky and the code appeared to work by chance.

A common recommendation is to declare one variable per line to avoid such mistakes. Also you should try to always initialize variables.

Answer (score 2):

The *wrong solution* does not initialize `rightsum` variable. Could be fixed this way:

```
       int rightsum = 0, leftsum = 0
```

Generally declaring multiple variables with singe declaration is confusing. Pointers, `const` qualifier and initialization are sources of it. So many prefer separate declarations of each variable

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that `int rightSum, leftSum = 0;` doesn't set `rightSum` to zero but rather to whatever value in memory was there previously.

With C++ I think it's what's called undefined behavior where you don't know what will happen if you write it that way and can't assume it will be set to zero. Better to do it explicitly, as in the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
int rightsum, leftsum = 0; // rightsum is not initialized here, only leftsum
```

Then the following code will probably lead to unexpected values :

```
rightsum += nums[i]; // add nums[i] to uninitialized variable
```